# Efficient way to download multiple profile pictures from the Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm currently using `https://graph.facebook.com/PROFILE_ID/picture` to display a user's Facebook profile picture. In some instance's I'm having to display hundreds at a time, using the above method is causing latency. An option I could use would be to download the profile picture to my CDN each time the user interact's with my site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you could use facebook [batch requests](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/batch/)